# Index was outside the bounds of the array in c#

Tags: c#, mysql, arrays

I want to insert MySqlDataReader read value into an array.but I get the exception "Index was outside the bounds of the array". Here is my code,

```
        string[] a = new string[1000];

        string myconstring = "SERVER=localhost;" + "DATABASE=alicosms;" + "UID=root;" + "PASSWORD=;";
        MySqlConnection mycon = new MySqlConnection(myconstring);
        string sql = "SELECT flag FROM sms_data_bankasia group by flag";
        MySqlCommand comd = mycon.CreateCommand();
        comd.CommandText = sql;
        mycon.Open();
        MySqlDataReader dtr = comd.ExecuteReader();
        count = 0;


        int i = 0;
            while (dtr.Read())
            {

                a[i] = dtr.GetValue(i).ToString();
                i++;

            }
```

What can I do.Any one can help me?

Comment: Go to your profile by clicking on your name, then you'll see all the questions that you have asked. Then open question by clicking on it and accept answer that was helpful by clicking on the tick on the left of the answer.

Comment: @evilone now I accept some answers,so I think you must help me.

Comment: @sumona Great! But I see that Jon already helped you and you already accept his answer :)

Comment: 2 answers are acceptable so what to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try cleaning your code a little and use a dynamically resizing `List<T>` to which you can add elements:

```
var result = new List<string>();
var myconstring = "SERVER=localhost;DATABASE=alicosms;UID=root;PASSWORD=;";
using (var con = new MySqlConnection(myconstring))
using (var cmd = con.CreateCommand())
{
    con.Open();
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT flag FROM sms_data_bankasia group by flag";
    using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            result.Add(reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("flag")));
        }
    }
}

string[] a = result.ToArray();
```

Comment: if I want to use only array then what I do @darin?

Comment: @sumona, look at the last line of my code sample. It converts the `List<T>` into an array.

Comment: @sumona, `var` is a keyword introduced in C# 3.0 allowing you to declare variables with implicit type: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383973.aspx If you are using an older .NET version which doesn't support this simply replace `var` with their respective type: MySqlConnection, MySqlCommand, MySqlReader, ...

Comment: It only provide count.But i need value.So What to do @darin?

Comment: @sumona, I don't understand what are you talking about. Count of what? Value of what?

Comment: I need different types of value stored in DB column.Bt i found only types.For example 100,100,102,102,102,105 r the value stored in db column.I need 100,102,105 not 3 types into the array @darin

Comment: @sumona, that's because you have grouped by the `flag` column in your SQL query and you are selecting only the `flag` in the resultset. Adapt your query to select other things like for example the count of records on each group or whatever information you need.

Comment: sorry I found it @darin tnax again

Comment: Thanx for ur conversion @darin.

Comment: Can u help me @darin to create timer using this list value and assign this timer for specific tusk?I am using VS 2005.

Answer (score 2):

This looks suspicious to me:

```
a[i] = dtr.GetValue(i).ToString();
```

That means you're fetching column 0 of row 0, column 1 of row 1, column 2 of row 2 etc... but you've only got a single column ("flag").

I suspect you meant:

```
a[i] = dtr.GetValue(0).ToString();
```

That will still fail if there are more than 1000 rows though - it would be better to use a `List<string>`:

```
List<string> data = new List<string>();
while (dtr.Read())
{
    data.Add(dtr.GetValue(0).ToString()); // Or call GetString
}
```

Comment: if I want to use array then what to do @Jon?

Comment: @sumona: Well, I would question *why* you want to use arrays first... but you could always call `ToArray()` on the list afterwards. The important thing is that an array always has a fixed size after you've created it - but you don't know how many rows will be in your result set.

Comment: If list are int type then what i write instead of "data.Add(dtr.GetValue(0).ToString());" @jon

Comment: @sumona: What do you mean by "if list are int type"? If you want to create a `List<int>` you probably want `dtr.GetInt32`.